# NotFoundException setting background attribute of a FrameLayout to a color state list, works fine setting textColor to same color

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to create text within a FrameLayout, so that it looks like this:

[image]

However, I want it to have a different color when touched. So, I created a color state list in XML, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/color_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/color_default" />
</selector>
```

This works completely fine when I set it to the `textColor` attribute of the TextView. However, when I set it to the `background` attribute of the enclosing FrameLayout, I get an exception!

Here is the XML code in the layout:

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:background="@color/green_selector"
android:padding="2dp"
android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp">

     <TextView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:textSize="17sp"
     android:textColor="@color/green_selector"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:text="Some Text"
     android:background="@color/white"
     android:gravity="center"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

The line `android:textColor="@color/green_selector"` works absolutely fine. However, `android:background="@color/green_selector"` gives me the following exception:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/green_selector.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0a00e6
    E/AndroidRuntime(25682):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3439)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25682):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25682):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3721)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25682):    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:480)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25682):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:101)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25682):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:97)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25682):    ... 28 more
    E/AndroidRuntime(25682): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #3: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
    E/AndroidRuntime(25682):    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:181)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25682):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:990)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25682):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:930)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25682):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3435)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25682):    ... 33 more
```

I get essentially the same error when I move the selector to res/drawable and change the line in the layout to `android:background="@drawable/green_selector"`

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?? According to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:background), this should be working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at your stacktrace:

```
<item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
```

As per the stacktrace, you need to define a background child instead of a color child in your selector.

**R.drawable.green_selector**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:background="@drawable/background_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:background="@drawable/background_default" />
</selector>
```

And because of that you also need to create the two new drawables: background_pressed, background_default like this:

**R.drawable.background_pressed**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/color_pressed" />
</shape>
```